# Package folder not created - Android

Tags: android, package, android-package-managers

I am creating an Android application. Under Android/data/package.com folder not created. Do I need to do anything for creating a directory under this folder? I am testing on Android 6.0 device.

Comment: are you using android-studio..?

Comment: Yes. Android studio 2.1.3

Comment: @Amsheer Just for clarification where r u checking, in device?

Comment: Can you sent the tree view of the folder structure

Comment: @Raghavendra I am checking Device Storage -> Android -> data

Comment: Exit the current application and try with new application. If this is not working then there r some issue in the Studio

Comment: @Amsheer when I see your question u r referring Android/data/ means I hope u r checking in device. As I know u can't see that its hidden. If u have rooted device or emulator u can see that

Comment: But all the other applications package folders are available under this location

Comment: @Amsheer some apps use external storage to store some temp files or their needs. So I think u haven't done anything to keep your app in external storage. So u can't see that. Basically your app in device's internal storage. Which no one have access.

Comment: @Raghavendra I tried that still it is not available...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Under Android/data/package.com folder not created

That directory will not be created until needed, because you start using `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getExternalCacheDir()`, or other `getExternal...()` methods on `Context`.

Comment: Wow you are great. I just add one System log System.out.println(getExternalCacheDir()); in my splash screen. Package folder created. Really awesome.

Comment: yes we can use appropriate getExternal Directory function to create package named folder along with corresponding directory under packages name folder.

Answer (score 0):

Every android app will be installed in internal storage except we manually say to android to install it in **external storage**. So you can't see your package which is in device's internal storage. Except you are testing it in Emulator/rooted device.

If you want to see your app package in external storage try this.

> Create a file in external storage

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the folder that you just created, Until you restart the device.
This is how you can create folder in android.

```
if(isExternalStorageAvail()) {
            File appRootDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "APP_NAME");
            if (!appRootDir.exists()) {
                appRootDir.mkdir();
            }
```

File appMediaImages = new File(appMedia.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Images");
                if (!appMediaImages.exists()) {
                    appMediaImages.mkdir();
                }

Comment: What is this isExternalStorageAvail()?

Comment: It is a user defined method to check external storage is available or not.